# PHP code for registering a user is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am this is some code for registering a user. The code works, and adds a new user. But it seems to ignore the part where it has to check if there is already a user registered with that username or email.

```
<?php
// Include database connection and functions here.
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
// The hashed password from the form
$password = $_POST['p'];
// Create a random salt
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
// Create salted password (Careful with the chilli)
$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members
WHERE username='$username'");
$username_check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$result_email = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members
WHERE email='$email'");
$email_check = mysqli_fetch_array($result_email);

if ($username == $username_check['username']){
    mysqli_close();
    header("..\..\..\?error12");
    exit;
    }else{

if($email == $email_check['email']){
    mysqli_close();
    header("..\..\..\?error13");
    exit;
    }else{

if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")){
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    $insert_stmt->execute();
    header("Location: '..\..\..\?success=1'");
    }else{
    header("Location: '..\..\..\?registrationfailed=1'");
}}}?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: con in /hermes/bosoraweb057/b2991/nf.domain.com/public_html/Bit/secure/sec_reg.php on line 15 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /hermes/bosoraweb057/b2991/nf.domain.com/public_html/Bit/secure/sec_reg.php on line 16 Notice: Undefined variable: con in /hermes/bosoraweb057/b2991/nf.domain.com/public_html/Bit/secure/sec_reg.php on line 16 Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /hermes/bosoraweb057/b2991/nf.domain.com/public_html/Bit/secure/sec_reg.php on line 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'";

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){

//This means no match was found in the database then proceed
    $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")){
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    $insert_stmt->execute();
    header("Location: '..\..\..\?success=1'");

}else{
//This username already exists
mysqli_close();
    header("..\..\..\?error12");
    exit;
}
```

The above could also be used to check the user e-mail too

Comment: It still lets the creation of account even if its the sane username